# Node/Socket.io - How to emit a function/data every x minutes

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a `Node` server that is using `socket.io`. I would like my `socket` object to emit some data to the connected browser once per minute on the minute. Ideally something like `setInterval()` but instead of calling every x minutes, look at the time and execute at on the minute.

I imagine it would look something like this, if I wanted to send every 1 minutes.

```
var data = "someData";
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit_every_x_minutes(1, 'myData', data)}
});
```

This would emit `"someData"` to the client socket periodically every 1 minute.

What is the correct way to emit every x minutes `socket.io`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use setInterval / setTimeout ?

```
var data = "someData";
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    setInterval(() => {
        socket.emit(1, 'myData', data)}
    }, 60 * 1000);
});
```

If you want on the minute, every minute, without a library:

```
var data = "someData";
const doEveryMinute = (socket) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
       setInterval(() => doEveryMinute(socket), 60000);
       socket.emit(1, 'myData', data)}
   }, (60 - date.getSeconds()) * 1000);
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    doEveryMinute(socket);
});
```

If accuracy is important, then you'll want something like  https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm looking for something that checks the time and executes on the minute, not every x minutes

Comment: He wrote just that?

Comment: Updated my answer for every minute on the minute. Probably not going to be as accurate as node-chron.

Answer (score 1):

You can use node-schedule or node-cron modules.

Visit : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

or

Visit: http://merencia.com/node-cron/